# Subset data.table based on value in column of type list

Tags: r, list, data.table, subset

So I have this case currently of a data.table with one column of type list.
This list can contain different values, `NULL` among other possible values.
I tried to subset the data.table to keep only rows for which this column has the value `NULL`.

Behold... my attempts below (for the example I named the column "ColofTypeList"):

```
DT[is.null(ColofTypeList)]
```

It returns me an `Empty data.table`.
Then I tried:

```
DT[ColofTypeList == NULL]
```

It returns the following error (I expected an error):

```
Error in .prepareFastSubset(isub = isub, x = x, enclos = parent.frame(),  : 
  RHS of == is length 0 which is not 1 or nrow (96). For robustness, no recycling is allowed (other than of length 1 RHS). Consider %in% instead.
```

(Just a precision my original data.table contains 96 rows, which is why the error message say such thing:

> which is not 1 or nrow (96).

The number of rows is not the point).
Then I tried this:

```
DT[ColofTypeList == list(NULL)]
```

It returns the following error:

```
Error: comparison of these types is not implemented
```

I also tried to give a list of the same length than the length of the column, and got this same last error.

So my question is simple: What is the correct data.table way to subset the rows for which elements of this "ColofTypeList" are `NULL` ?

EDIT: here is a reproducible example

```
DT<-data.table(Random_stuff=c(1:9),ColofTypeList=rep(list(NULL,"hello",NULL),3))
```

Have fun!

Comment: Please show a small reproducioble example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a `list`, we can loop through the list and apply the `is.null` to return a logical `vector`

```
DT[unlist(lapply(ColofTypeList, is.null))]
#   ColofTypeList anotherCol
#1:                        3
```

Or another option is `lengths`

```
DT[lengths(ColofTypeList)==0]
```

#### data

```
DT <- data.table(ColofTypeList = list(0, 1:5, NULL, NA), anotherCol = 1:4)
```

Comment: Yes, I did that also. And then ? Once you have TRUE for some elements what should I do ?

Comment: @YoannPageaud  I was about to ask that question.  What is your expected output?  Is it to subset the rows of data, then `DT[DT[, unlist(lapply(ColofTypeList, is.null))]]`

Comment: The expected output is to get a data.table with all the rows for which this column of type list contains a NULL element.

Comment: Just saw your updated answer: this works I agree, but is it the current data.table way ?

Comment: @YoannPageaud  Yes, `lapply` is valid in `data.table`

Comment: I am not talking about the lapply part, this I agree is fine in data.table, I am questionning about the "DT[DT[" part.

Comment: @YoannPageaud  yes, true, I didn't test it earlier.  THe one `DT` will also work

Comment: @YoannPageaud  Can you check the update with the example

Comment: This part is a win to me: `DT[lengths(ColofTypeList)==0]`

Answer (score 1):

I have found another way that is also quite nice:

```
DT[lapply(ColofTypeList, is.null)==TRUE]
```

It is also important to mention that using `isTRUE()` doesn't work.