# Subset data.table based on different kind of values in column of type list

Tags: r, list, data.table

After asking this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59198204/subset-data-table-based-on-value-in-column-of-type-list) I realized that there was not much on Stackoverflow to answer other specific cases (not only subsetting rows based on `NULL` elements of a list column).

Here is a dummy data.table that can be used as an example:

```
DT<-data.table(Random_stuff=c(1:12),ColofTypeList=rep(list(NULL,"hello",5,NA),3))
```

This example contain NULLs, NAs, integers, and characters.

So the question is how to subset a data.table following different type of values when these values are in a column of type list ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an answer which, is not exhaustive, and certainly not the only one possible, shows how to subset rows from a data.table for each type of values in the column of type list.

Subset DT rows containing NULL in 'ColofTypeList':

```
DT[lapply(ColofTypeList, is.null)==TRUE]
```

Subset DT rows containing NAs in 'ColofTypeList':

```
DT[lapply(ColofTypeList, is.na)==TRUE]
```

Subset DT rows containing the character 'hello' in 'ColofTypeList':

```
DT[lapply(ColofTypeList, grepl, pattern="hello")==TRUE]
```

Subset DT rows containing the integer 5 in 'ColofTypeList':

```
DT[lapply(ColofTypeList, match,5)==1]
```

So through all these case each time the key is to use `lapply()` directly on the column of type list.
While the first 3 cases return a `logical` (boolean), the last and 4th case using `match()` counts the occurence of the value you look for. Which is the reason why I wrote `==1`.

I find this way of writing quite elegant and simple for subsetting rows.

Again, I might miss something already documented somewhere else for subsetting rows of a data.table based on content of a column of type list, but I did not find much about these cases.
So I hope this will be useful to those facing this.
Please share your solutions if you already had to deal with this to see if there could be a simpler way.

Answer (score 0):

what about creating a new column that you can easily subset on?

```
DT<-data.table(Random_stuff=c(1:12),ColofTypeList=rep(list(NULL,"hello",5,NA),3))
DT[, type := sapply(ColofTypeList, typeof)]
```

which lets you subset as follows...

```
DT[type=="character"]
   Random_stuff ColofTypeList      type
1:            2         hello character
2:            6         hello character
3:           10         hello character

DT[type=="logical"]
   Random_stuff ColofTypeList    type
1:            4            NA logical
2:            8            NA logical
3:           12            NA logical

DT[type=="NULL"]
   Random_stuff ColofTypeList type
1:            1               NULL
2:            5               NULL
3:            9               NULL

DT[type=="double"]
   Random_stuff ColofTypeList   type
1:            3             5 double
2:            7             5 double
3:           11             5 double
```

Comment: Yes it works, you are right.
But why using a 2 lines solution when you can achieve it in 1 line :) ?
I would have actually use your way before finding direct use of lapply(...)=T was possible...

Btw do you have any idea if there is documentation somewhere about such subsetting on column list ?